# CurrentRadioAccessTechnology return nil means no connection to cellular network?

Tags: ios, reachability, core-telephony

I saw some code use the following logic to check the local network connection:

Use `Reachiability` to check whether connect to Wifi (Test address `169.254.0.0`). If no wifi, then check the `currentRadioAccessTechnology`,  return `nil` indicate no connection to the network, otherwise mean 2g, 3g or 4g.

`Core Telephony` is lack of docs, it just say:

> The current radio access technology the device is registered with. May
>   be NULL if device is not registered on any network.